# Bing webmaster API GetKeywordStats UnknownError and empty response

Tags: php, json, bing-api

I'm trying to get [keyword statistics using the bing webmaster API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554164.aspx) by sending JSON GET requests. The parameters are as following:

```
List<KeywordStats> GetKeywordStats(  
    string q,  
    string country, //optional  
    string language //optional  
)
```

So at first I generated my uri this way:

> https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/api.svc/json/GetKeywordStats?apikey=myAPIKey&q=kreeft&country=BE&language=nl

This returned the following response:

> status: 400
>   {
>       "ErrorCode": 2,
>       "Message": "UnknownError"
>   }

Trying to solve the problem I simplified my url by not setting the optional parameters resulting in the following query:

> https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/api.svc/json/GetKeywordStats?apikey=myApiKey&q=kreeft

The response on this query was even more puzzling:

> status: 200
>   {"d":[]}

Which just looks like an empty response to me.
I queried those links both from localhost (using postman) and from my webserver at one.com, both giving the same results.

So I have 2 questions actually:
- Why do I have empty responses
- Why are my parameters not accepted

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The country code must be lowercase, and the language code must include the country component (in uppercase). yes, it is inconsistent and not specified anywhere.

```
https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/api.svc/json/GetKeywordStats?apikey=myAPIKey&q=kreeft&country=be&language=nl-BE
```

For more, see the blog article: http://bing-webmaster-api.analyticsedge.com/2014/05/getkeywordstats/